# GPIO current drive strength test circuit

Tags: current, gpio, drive-strength

I have GPIO channels in my controller.

The controller manufacturer does not know exact number of drive strength of the GPIOs.

The controller is a digital signal processor (DSP) board. I want to control a stepper motor using my GPOIs, but the input of stepper motor driver has specific requiremen t(input voltage and input current.) If the input current of the stepper motor driver is higher than GPIO's drive strength, the GPIO may be damaged.

Is there a simple circuit to test GPIO drive strength using an oscilloscope without damaging the GPIO?

----I figured it out that GPIO strenght test circuit was not a good idea. The DSP controller is kind of custom-made one, and only several tens were produced. I contacted one of the DSP controller users and found that the GPIOs have enough drive strength for my stepper motor inputs. I prefer the opto-isolator type connection since it does not share ground and noise

Comment: Which controller is it, what you know about it, and what more do you want to know? Why it is important to know it, and for what purpose it will be used? And do you mean DC or AC load driving ability?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit this new information into your question rather than adding it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question. Also, please add some actual values to it. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just add a transistor? Doesn't matter what the drive strength is, then.

Comment: Also, if the manufacturer doesn't know the maximum output current of the chip's GPIOs, then that manufacturer is unfit to produce microcontrollers. EVERY microcontroller should have an "absolute maximum ratings" section in its datasheet; and the maximum GPIO drive currents should be listed there.

Comment: Give the name and a link to the datasheet of your DSP board. The board manufacturer may not know it but from its schematic or BoM it may be easier to find.

Comment: @SodAlmighty, maybe try a bit calmer for the new OP, please. But the Absolute Maximum specs are the point beyond which the part may be damaged or operate unreliably, so they're not the operating limits. Instead, the max. GPIO output current should be taken from the operating characteristics.

Comment: @Chang, please can you delete your last comment and instead edit its information into your question. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As said before, please can you edit new information into your question rather than adding it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question from a lot of different places. Thanks.